# Java multithreaded server *sometimes* throws SocketException (Socket closed) in ServerSocket.accept() method

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

I've been investigating this issue for hours and hours and I cannot come up with a decent solution or an explanation as to why this exception (java.net.SocketException: Socket closed) is getting thrown. My last approach is now to ask you guys.

I've created a simple server-client app for testing purposes (the 'real' application uses the same logic though), see below.

If I repeatably invoke the same test-case (for example through TestNG's *invocationcount* annotation parameter or by using a simple for-loop), at some point there will be a ***java.net.SocketException: Socket closed***.

The test case below basically just starts the server (opens the server socket), waits a couple of millis and then closes socket again. Closing the server socket involves opening a socket so that the server will return from the ServerSocket.accept() method (see Server#shutdown()).

I though it might be a multithreading issue with the code right after the ServerSocket.accept()-line. So I've surrounded it temporarily with a synchronized-block - didn't help either.

Do you have any idea why this exception gets thrown?

Best,
Chris

***Server.java*** looks like this:

```
package multithreading;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Server {

private ServerSocket serverSocket;
private boolean isShuttingDown;
private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Server.class);

public void start() throws Exception {
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5000);
        isShuttingDown = false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Starting up the server failed - aborting", e);
    }

    while (true) {
        try {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

            if (!isShuttingDown) {
                new Thread(new EchoRequestHandler(socket)).start();
            } else {
                logger.info("Server is going to shutdown");
                break;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error occured while waiting for new connections, stopping server", e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
}

public synchronized boolean isRunning() {
    if (serverSocket != null && serverSocket.isBound() && !serverSocket.isClosed() && !isShuttingDown) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public synchronized void shutdown() throws IOException {
    if (isRunning()) {
        isShuttingDown = true;
        if (serverSocket != null && !serverSocket.isClosed()) {
            try {
                /*
                 * since the server socket is still waiting in it's accept()
                 * method, just closing the server socket would cause an
                 * exception to be thrown. By quickly opening a socket
                 * (connection) to the server socket and immediately closing
                 * it again, the server socket's accept method will return
                 * and since the isShuttingDown flag is then false, the
                 * socket will be closed.
                 */
                new Socket(serverSocket.getInetAddress(), serverSocket.getLocalPort()).close();

                serverSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error("Closing the server socket has failed - aborting now.", e);
                throw e;
            }
        }
    } else {
        throw new IOException("Server socket is already closed which should not be the case.");
    }
}
}
```

The test class does the following:

```
package multithreading;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Testing {

// @Test(invocationCount=10, skipFailedInvocations=true)
@Test
public void loadTest() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        final Server s = new Server();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    s.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }).start();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        gracefullyShutdownServer(s);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}

private void gracefullyShutdownServer(final Server server) throws InterruptedException {
    try {
        server.shutdown();
        while (server.isRunning()) {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}

}
```

The stack trace looks as follows:

```
ERROR 2011-03-13 16:14:23,537 [Thread-6] multithreading.Server: Error occured while waiting for new connections, stopping server
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:390)
at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:453)
at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:421)
at multithreading.Server.start(Server.java:26)
at multithreading.Testing$1.run(Testing.java:18)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:390)
at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:453)
at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:421)
at multithreading.Server.start(Server.java:26)
at multithreading.Testing$1.run(Testing.java:18)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Comment: Providing the stack trace of the exception that's troubling you would be nice.

Comment: @Mat: Just added the stacktrace (sorry for not posting it in the first place, stupid of me)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

J.N. is correct concerning the way you should be handling the close.

As for the why this is not working, I think the race is that your server code reads `isShuttingDown` with no synchronization. I don't see why the value change should be visible immediately to the server thread. So it might very well go for another round.

So as J.N. said: deal with the exception in the server when accepting. If you want to know whether the exception is *probably* being raised by your code doing `close` on the socket, keep your `isShuttingDown` around be make sure you access it safely. (Either a `synchronized (this) {}` block, or write a very short synchronized accessor.)

In this specific case I think making `isShuttingDown` *volatile* is sufficient, as detailed in this developerWorks article [Java theory and practice: Managing volatility](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp06197.html). But be careful with that, it's not a magic bullet.

Comment: The link given is no longer valid, thanks for the info though :)

Answer (score 4):

As specified in this [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#close%28%29) link, Opening a socket to close another one is a mistake. Calling close on your socket should cancel the "accept" on its own by throwing an exception you can catch and ignore safely.